# Create a map that highlights regions when links clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I need to make a map (with HTML5 and/or JavaScript) which highlights certain areas when associated links are clicked, so the map doesn't need to be directly interactive, I just need it to be able to handle click events of the links.

Is there a plugin or website I can use to create a simple map in the area of my choosing at the city level? I've had a look at https://www.zeemaps.com, but from what I can tell that just allows you to create annotated/highlighted maps, not interactive maps.

Comment: http://kartograph.org/showcase/usa-projection/

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/. For the image mapping, you can find any software that can map the image with specified region as the element would be like this :

```
<area href="#" color="blue" shape="poly" coords="40,55,27,46,16,47,10,76,10,80,14,81,12,85,9,87,9,90,12,91,13,96,16,98,22,96,26,99,33,99,34,103,32,109,29,112,36,114,37,119,37,127,40,132,38,139,43,142,49,144,52,146,49,150,49,155,50,159,53,165,57,164,65,169,69,175,74,175,81,173,91,176,96,175,106,169,108,166,112,170,115,173,121,172,123,184,129,188,133,187,135,182,142,176,145,173,148,166,151,163,153,156,157,149,151,144,151,138,155,137,155,130,158,127,157,121,150,118,144,117,138,119,136,115,134,111,137,108,135,103,135,99,130,91,136,85,133,80,135,76,139,71,137,64,139,60,141,56,145,52,148,52,148,46,141,41,142,32,134,27,128,20,128,17,129,15,124,11,115,11,114,23,114,30,113,38,112,43,109,44,103,43,97,49,91,50,89,55,84,59,80,60,77,61,75,59,61,52,51,46" alt="" data-type=" Highlands">
```

They make the `onclick` event handler which is triggered when you click on specified area/region. Go through to the Doc link of course everything there.